# How can I copy message filters to another account in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to copy all Filter Rules in Message Filters window from one account to another.

(https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found solution:

1. Close Thunderbird.
2. Go to directory:
   `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\<profile>\ImapMail\<mailserver>\msgFilterRules.dat`
3. Copy `msgFilterRules.dat` to another mailserver or edit or **do whatever you want**.
4. Run Thunderbird.
5. Enjoy!

*Source:* https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Thunderbird_Back_Up_Mail__Message_Filters.html

Comment: If you are trying to switch from POP to IMAP (like me), the POP account message filter rules are in `Profiles\<profile>\Mail\<mailserver>` but they can be copied over to an account living in the `ImapMail` folder without any issue.

Comment: in true and modern OS it is in: /home/username/.thunderbird/somename.default-release-1/Mail/my.mailserver.org/msgFilterRules.dat  for POP and for IMAP   /home/username/.thunderbird/somename.default-release-1/ImapMail/my.mailserver.org/msgFilterRules.dat